# How to speed up working with a 7000-page document in Word 2021?

Tags: microsoft-word

I used to journal with Word 2010, and opening and jumping to the end of the document (I have a custom toolbar button for it) was relatively fast, like half a minute. Now with the latest fancy Word, it takes over a minute. Is there some kind of hidden or advanced setting that could help quicken the process? Perhaps by disabling a non-essential feature?

I'm aware that both versions can be installed at once, and I'm defaulting to editing only this document with the old version. It just doesn't play nice with high-dpi screens.

Comment: Are you using .DOC or .DOCX?

Comment: Password-protected .docx, 10MB large, no images.

Comment: Saving it as .doc (even if encryption is less good in the old format), does speed it up to a usable level!

Comment: I suggest looking into the Zettelkasten method, there’s plenty of software available for that. It works for me, I don’t write nearly as much though.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this would be to put aside Word (not just Word, but any word processor) and switch to a text editor. I can't think of any feature a word processor has to offer to journaling that would make it worth the overhead you're experiencing. Barring that, there are specialized applications for journaling, and some of them have mobile versions and can use cloud storage, so you could write wherever and whenever inspiration strikes.

But your question is about Word, and my solution doesn't answer your question.

If I had to use a word processor for a *seven thousand page* document, I'd do  one of two things:

- Switch from the native format to plain text. (If you need markup for some reason, [markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/) is almost trivial to learn. We use it here to mark up posts.) The switch will reduce your file size significantly and give your computer much less to do when opening and working with the file; or
- Break up the document into more manageable chunks. You must have been working on that journal for years. (I admire your discipline; I've tried journaling and can't seem to stick with it for more than a couple of days.) Breaking it into separate docs for each year might do it. Even better (IMHO), break it into months <del>and create a master document for each year</del>. *Note: I have been advised that Word's difficulties with Master Documents have yet to be addressed. Please do not use that feature.*

Wow, though. Seven thousand pages. I'm not kidding. That's impressive.

Comment: yes, working on any single documents that's longer than a few hundred pages is a bad idea

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I can endure the slowness when merging to a single master every once in a while. But for everyday opening, I could do with monthly or yearly, whichever is fast in the latest Word.

I'm a web dev (I know .md), and it pains me to have a single doc and no git :D and have been thinking of a better approach. Of course it's backed up.

I started it in 2007, and almost every day is documented. I liked this format because of the ease with which I can search and jump to results in it, as I often read old days where I search by an event, not by exact year or date.

Comment: Do not use the "Master Documents" feature in Word. https://addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart It can destroy your work. If you break it up and need to bring it all into one document, use Word MVP Graham Mayor's free Boiler application. http://www.gmayor.com/Boiler.htm

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I thought the problems with Master Documents had been resolved. I'd say I can't believe such a useful feature hasn't been properly addressed, but as we're talking about Microsoft, I won't.

Comment: @Firsh-justifiedgrid.com Searching isn't an issue with grep.

Comment: Master Documents: The MVPs tell me that the problems have not been resolved.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Sad. One of the many reasons I hated when my (former) employer transitioned from WordPerfect 6 for DOS to Word was that I'd written a rather large employee manual using WP's master document system and didn't dare translate the old system to the new. i essentially had to print a couple hundred files one at a time whenever the manual was updated.

Comment: As I said in my page, you can do things with the Master Documents feature. However, you need to be careful and essentially create the document, print, and destroy the document. No editing of subs within the MD structure.